# Dual supply op-amp, 0V on input yet small voltage on the out

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-source

I've been working on a constant current source design and have come up with the schematic below (heavily inspired from the LTC6082 [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/60812fd.pdf)), however, there is a small issue. When my input voltage is 0V there is around 1.4 mV on the output of U10A (TP31). I believe this is a constant offset but I can not see anywhere that justifies why this is or perhaps how to deal with it. It seems like a very large offset and something well beyond what the data sheet is expecting. The op-amp is on a 4-layer PCB with dual supply rails.

I believe the offset could be accounted for in software however it would be nice to prevent it happening altogether or at least understand it?
Any help much appreciated.

[image: Schematic Screenshot]

Comment: Which output has the unexpected voltage? The output of U10A? The output of U10B? The ISRC node?

Comment: @nanofarad U10A - sorry I forgot to add that crucial detail. Question updated.

Comment: Is ISRC_ADJ also a DAC output or a trimpot to GND?

Comment: Have you accounted for the input-offset error of all the amplifier stages multiplied by the gain?

Comment: Was this tested with a load? Your schematic doesn't show the load. This is a current source, so if there is no load the circuit will raise the voltage to try to induce the current.

Comment: @devnull Its a digital trim pot to GND yes.

Comment: @BrianB It has been tested with a load and it performed well. When the input is 0V though the current setting should also be 0V and so the voltage is somewhat unexplained. Overall it is a voltage controlled current source.

Comment: Well, seeing as how it's a current source and not a voltage source, an unexpected voltage of 1.4 mV isn't a problem, in and of itself. If you connect a 1 mΩ resistor as the load, do you end up with 1.4 A of current? I'm guessing not. If you connect a 1 Ω resistor, do you end up with 1.4 mA of current? If so, is 1.4 mA outside of the tolerance that you need? If your current source never produces a current which is higher or lower than you need, then it sounds to me like you don't have a problem.

Comment: *" It has been tested with a load"* As @TannerSwett mentioned, the value of the load is relevant. Could you add it to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Using "almost ideal" opamps and adding the input voltage offsets with the worst polarities and values, you can see that the output current for a 0V input and a load from 0 to 1e6 is not perfect:

[image]

[image]

And the output of the opamp you mentioned also varies around the value you informed, considering a 100k load and testing the ranges of all the input offsets:

[image]

Note that this simulation tests only the influence of the specified input voltage offset. The trimpot I asked about in the comments affects both the differential and common mode gain of the differential amplifier.